# Rails project solution needed?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am creating a on line web  project in rails which has a master DB and slave DB. When a row is updated on the master, it should also be updated on the slave db.

What kind of design should I implement in writing routine program for updating master to slave?

Comment: What database? Every single database out there has a replication setup for master-slave configurations.

Comment: I am using mysql database,my server app has a database and client app has a database,so i need to update some data from server database to client database with out any conflict in updating and this should be a routine program.So what should be design consideration?

Comment: Is this a rails specific question? Or do you want general advice related to your question?

Comment: Yes all suggestion are welcome.

Comment: This best done [via MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html), which is natively supported and easy to setup. It happens independently of your application code.

Comment: Thanks Michael,This is the stuff i looking for,thanks for all for providing valuable comments.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael)'s Suggestion:

[Intro to The Why's of Replication](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/replication.html)

[MySQL Documentation For Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

[How to Setup MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks NoahClark for the help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see this is your first question. One thing that will help you in the future is accepting answers that help you. Your "accepted answers" percentage is shown when you ask questions and many people avoid answering them if your percentage falls beneath a certain threshold.